# Proof of Krull's Height Theorem for irreducible affine varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry, krull-dimension, dimension-theory-algebra

I'm trying to solve exercise 11.3.H in Vakil's notes (http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/216blog/FOAGnov1817public.pdf). We want to show that if $X = \mathrm{Spec} A$ is an irreducible affine $k$-variety (so $A$ an integral domain of finite type over $k$) and $Z$ is an irreducible component of $V(r_1, \dots, r_\ell) \subseteq X$, then $\mathrm{codim}(Z, X) \leq \ell$.

Vakil suggests reducing to the case of $V(r_1, \dots, r_\ell) = Z$. Once we have this, we can apply Theorem 11.2.9 from the notes to get $\mathrm{codim}(Z, X) = \dim(A) - \dim(A/(r_1, \dots, r_\ell)) \leq \ell$ (this inequality can be shown by looking at transcendence degrees and applying $\mathrm{dim}(R) = \mathrm{tr.deg.}_k(\mathrm{Frac}(R))$ if $R$ is an integral domain that's also a finitely generated $k$-algebra (11.2.1 in the notes).

My difficulty is how to perform this reduction. Vakil suggests localizing something. If $Z$ corresponds to the prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ in $A$ (minimal among those containing $(r_1, \dots, r_\ell)$, then localizing at $\mathfrak{p}$ gives a Noetherian integral domain $A_\mathfrak{p}$ in which $V(r_1, \dots, r_\ell) = \{\mathfrak{p} A_\mathfrak{p}\} = V(\mathfrak{p})$ and $\mathrm{dim}(A_\mathfrak{p}) = \mathrm{ht}(\mathfrak{p})$, but $A_\mathfrak{p}$ is not necessarily of finite type over $k$ anymore (for example $k[x]_{(x)}$ is not a finitely generated $k$-algebra).

Any comments would be appreciated.

Comment: If $V(r_1,\ldots, r_l)=Z_1\cup Z_2\cup\cdots \cup Z_p$are the irreducible components, take some thin vanishing on all the $Z_i, i>1$, but not vanishing on $Z_1$. If you invert it, you still have a finitely generated algebra and only $Z_1$ survives.

Comment: Ah, problem solved. Thank you!

Comment: @gvv I am working on this same question, but the difficult part for me is: how does one show $dim(A)-dim(A/(r_1,\ldots,r_l))\le l$?

Comment: @A.S. Since $A$ is a Noetherian integral domain of finite type over a field, we know $\mathrm{dim}(A) = \mathrm{tr.deg.}_k(\mathrm{Frac}(A))$ by 11.2.1 in Vakil. We know the same thing for the quotient $A/(r_1, \dots, r_n)$ (do you see why?). This reduces the inequality you want to one about transcendence degrees. This is easier as each relation you mod out by can introduce at most one linear dependence.

Comment: @gvv, thanks for your response. However, the issue for me is to make precise what it means that "each relation you mod out by can introduce at most one linear dependence". I found an argument now (the one starting on the second page of these notes http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~bdrew/612/lec/612lec17.pdf) but I can't see a way that is simpler than this (roughly to use Noether normalization and properties of the field norm).

Comment: @A.S. In order to make that statement clearer, you could think about the corresponding statement for vector spaces. In order to compare the two, you need some notion of a "transcendence basis." If you're not comfortable with this maybe you should check out exercise 11.2.A in Vakil or a standard algebra book like Dummit and Foote. I understand that this sudden emergence of transcendental field extensions may seem technical, but I promise it's not that bad. Your link wasn't loading properly for me. We're implicitly using Noether normalization (proof of 11.2.1) already.